# Convert a number to a time in hiveql

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Currently I am calculating the difference of two Timestamps (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) by session ID (rows).  Once I am able to get that information, I join with a date table and average out the times to get a specific number.
I am looking for a way to convert a number, example 4.5, into a time of 00:04:30 (4 minutes, 30 seconds).
I do not want to include any date functionality, therefore this code would exclude the 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.

Here is the logic I am using:

```
select t_date_dim.greg_dt,
    avg(Big.Session_Length) as Session_Length
from (
    select unix_timestamp(Big.MaximumTimestamp) - unix_timestamp(Big.MinimumTimestamp) as Session_Length
    from Big
    )
inner join t_date_dim on big.dt = t_date_dim.greg_dt
```

Comment: P.s. The query is invalid.

Comment: I tried to cut down the query to get to strictly the foundation of my issue.  I noticed my naming conventions are incorrect. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

```
hive> with t as (select 1234 as session_length) -- in seconds 
      select printf("%02d:%02d", session_length div 60,session_length % 60) 
      from t
      ;
OK
_c0
20:34
```

---

- [jira HIVE-2695: Add PRINTF() Udf](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2695)
- [java.util.Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)
- [GenericUDFPrintf.java](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFPrintf.java)

Comment: I haven't seen the "printf" function in Hive before.  What is it and how does it work?

Comment: @MParisian - See added links in my answer